# XAMPP MYSQL PHPMYADMIN database import Error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

Having a heck of a time getting a site running locally.

Working with XAMPP for open source preferences over WAMP (no one is sure what WAMPS GPML license is apparently).

I've tried compatibility modes : None : Oracle : Traditional : MYSQL40
I've tried encoding : utf8 : utf16

Apache and SQL run perfectly but when using PHPMyAdmin to import the website database I continually get errors regarding syntax errors in the table data itself.
I attribute this to XAMPPs default incorporation of MariaDB in the latest release I'm using. I can import this database dump easily on another host's virtual SQL 5.5 server.  I can also upload this database into WAMP without errors.

Looking this row over it doesn't stand out from any other rows empty fields or data fields.

```
MySQL: Error

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
Field1, Field2, Field3, etc,... atline 123
```

Interestingly the first table is created and stops short.  The sequence of rows are consistent until 241 jumps to 245, then 272, and then crashes with error above on row 447?

MySql Error logs are also changing based on encoding options. Not sure if I'm digging myself into a hole while I resolve the unknown.

Most of the Event Viewer MySql Error Logs show:

```
Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
```

Just upgrade MySql, what type of an update is that? What about upgrading MariaDB?

And a few of these:

```
Incorrect definition of table mysql.proc: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVA
```

Playing with export options I get this error from the first Create Table Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Table1" (
  "PRIMARY" int(123) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "COLUMN1" varchar(123) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  "COLUMN2" int(123) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "COLUMN3" varchar(123) DEFAULT NULL,
   ETC...

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"TABLE" (
  "ID" int(123) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "COLUMN1" varchar(123) N' at line 1
```

Currently picking through the data dump on Notepad++

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your error code is #1064 just google it  (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064)

Comment: This general syntax error is hard to narrow down because I'm new to this project and the row throwing an error is perfectly normalized. I've been trying different variations of 'encoding' and 'compatibility'. Using UTF16 and MYSQL40 compatability I see the syntax error move to a meta statement for Create Table: syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=XXXX'.

Comment: Why would the Primary column appear out of sequence in the export file, right at the location where import is stopping?   It's also importing collation as utf8_swedish_ci for no reason that I can tell.

Comment: Which XAMPP and phpMyAdmin versions?

Answer (score 0):

Not doube-quotes (") around column names, backtics (`).

Nothing you mentioned indicates a need to change the `CHARACTER SET` (encoding).

One of your errors points to `sql_mode`; let's see it in context.

Comment: Since the tables import fine, as is, over at star field, I wonder why the double-quotes around column names generated by phpmyadmin export are causing problems?  The origin MySql phpmyadmin seems a little shady with no https on cpanel backend.  We also had some primary keys disappearing on certain tables over the years from errors in the existing web system which I attempted to fix-n-fill.